# Windows Media Player not found in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, media-player

I downloaded and installed Windows 8.1 Pro N from MSDN and I need Windows Media Player, but it is not there. It simply does not exist. But I need it.

Comment: Updated the answer. Should solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Both N and KN version of windows do not have media player and the underlying technology. Even if one doesn't use Media player it is required by other players. It is provided separately.

Here is one for Windows 8. Should also work for 8.1:

<del>http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30685</del> (Does not work on Windows 8.1 N)

**Update 2:** Media Feature Pack for N and KN versions of Windows 8.1 is out

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744

Comment: I was about to install Windows 8.1 N. I geuss we have to wait for the feature pack.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly to install Media Foundation Platform .dll's, which I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. as you said.. you installed the "N" version.. which is a special version of Windows without Media Player...

A Hotfix is(will be) available to install the Media Player on top...

Comment: this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Well, looks like all these downloads are "combined", both N and non-N included. But it never asked me. I had no choice. Looks like all Europeans are being punished automatically. And there is no hotfix (yet).

Answer (score 0):

The meida feature pack is only currently available for editions of windows 8N not 8.1. Seeing as 8.1 will be ofically relased on October 17 a 8.1 meida feature pack will most probally become available then.